# Release multiple assemblies in single .net core package

Tags: c#, nuget, .net-core, nuget-package, nuget-spec

I'm trying to release my library ([lz4net](https://github.com/MiloszKrajewski/lz4net)) for .NET Core. The library "architecture" differs a little from "normal" as it contains multiple assemblies but only one should be referenced, the other ones are just its dependencies. They are not separate packages though.

So, assembly `LZ4.dll` should be referenced by the application, while `LZ4pn.dll` should not, it just should be there as `LZ4.dll` (main one) may use it. `LZ4pn.dll" is not usable on its own therefore it is not released as separate package.

It seems to be working fine in: net2, net4, and pcl, but it netcore does not "see" `LZ4pn.dll` if it is not referenced by application.

NOTE: I've checked and `C:\Users\xxx\nuget\packages\lz4net\1.0.11.93\lib\netstandard1.6` (after installation of .nupkg) do contain both assemblies.

So, `LZ4pn.net` is not in `<references>` section as it should not be referenced by application directly. It is not in `<dependencies>` section as it is not external dependency which needs to be separately downloaded. It is just there - in `netstandard1.6` subfolder of nuget package. .NET Framework (2+) work fine but .NET Core does not discover this assembly.

Any help?
Maybe you know some open-source package which uses the same approach (multi-assembly packages which reference only top assembly)?